# Can´t run project after clean up in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I had a bug in my xaml Designer in my Project so went on with the standard procedure cleanup project and rebuild it. But after cleaning I can´t rebuild the project because it says that VisualStudio can´t find the project exe in the bin/Debug folder...

The error field in VisualStudio shows me that Axlmp.exe was shut down with the 1163019603 error code. It´s funny it tells me that I should rebuild the project to run it, when it doesn´t work.

I did nothing else. Only pressing clean and then everythin exploded. VisualStudio doesn´t know my custom wpf controls, too.

Yes, I closed it and started it again but the problem still exists.

Comment: You can once try to make the VS to default or reinstall incase you feel that problem lies with your Visual studio

Comment: Rebuild all projects within your solution one after another. Starting with the one with **no** dependencies on other projects. This helps you finding out what Project causes the issue

Comment: I know what project causes the issue. This is the project I cleaned but I can´t rebuild it. It says that it can´t find the coresponding .exe in the /bin/Debug folder.

Comment: Visual Studio has a thing called ShadowCache located at `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache`.
Cleaning that Folder did solve a lot of weird Issues for me over the last years.

Comment: Okey that worked for me. That´s really suprising when something like that happens. Btw where you found this solution?